# Remove records from has_many Rails association with a single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble removing records from a has_many association in Rails without triggering unnecessary queries. Essentially, I have a model which has a has_many relation on it, and I want to remove multiple records from it based on some criteria. I want to be able to simultaneously keep the association up to date, but also remove the records from the database, and only require one DELETE query to do this. I've tried assigning to the relation with the new objects (which generates unnecessary UPDATE queries) and calling delete_all (which makes one query but doesn't update the association).

Comment: Rails need to find each object you want to delete in order to run the callbacks (`before_` and `after_` destroy) on each. If you want to skip that process, which is a slippery slope, you might want to create a service object which holds all the logic about this "delete all related objects" and reset the association

Comment: I think resetting the association is also not optimal, because if the association gets accessed later on, the objects will have to get refetched, even though we know what should be in the relation.

Comment: IMO, you should not try to reduce the SQL queries and redefine Rails' behaviour. It can lead to various issues, not visible at first sight but much later when you whole app has been using it for months...

Comment: When you say "keep the association up to date", do you mean in memory? In other words: you want to execute a single `DELETE`, but at the same time also update your in-memory object without having to query the DB again?

Comment: @henrebotha yes, that is my intention. I want the in memory has many association to stay up to date with what's in the database.

Comment: @mp94 A `reload` at the end of delete_all should successfully correct the in-memory association data.

Comment: It would yes, but I feel like this shouldn't be necessary because based on the queries I have ran, I have all the data already in memory, but I can't assign to the `has_many` association without doing more queries. The reload will generate a SELECT query I believe.

Comment: This is a frustratingly tricky problem! You can do `parent.children.replace(filtered_subset_of_children)`, which will execute the `DELETE` & update the in-memory object at the same time (I think); but then you have to either filter the children ahead of time (in which case you're just displacing the extra queries, not removing them), or filter them in memory. Seems almost impossible to generate a true `DELETE WHERE foo = bar` that will update the cache...

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods to delete records from a relation. `destroy` deletes all the related records one at a time, running the callbacks on each deleted record. `delete_all` deletes all the records in one query and does not run the callbacks.

So, in a model you could have:

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :statements, dependent: :delete_all
```

and when you delete the customer

```
pry(main) foo = Customer.first
pry(main)> foo.destroy
  (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (290.4ms)  DELETE FROM `statements` WHERE `statements`.`customer_id` = 3
  SQL (2.6ms)  DELETE FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`id` = 3
```

All done in one swell foop, no callbacks on the deleted.

or -

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :statements, dependent: :destroy
```

and when you delete the customer

```
pry(main) foo = Customer.first
pry(main)> foo.destroy
  (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  Statement Load (25.0ms)  SELECT `statements`.* FROM `statements` WHERE `statements`.`customer_id` = 4
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM `statements` WHERE `statements`.`id` = 9023
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM `statements` WHERE `statements`.`id` = 9024
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM `statements` WHERE `statements`.`id` = 9025
  . . . etc etc etc . . .
```

Each dependent record deleted one at a time, callbacks run on each deleted.

And `delete_all` and `destroy` can be run on any result set with similar effects. So if you wanted to have some filter on the related records:

```
pry(main) foo = Customer.first
pry(main)> bar = foo.statements.where(some_param: 42)
pry(main)> bar.delete_all
  SQL (4.2ms)  DELETE FROM `statements` WHERE `statements`.`customer_id` = 7 AND `notices`.`some_param` = 42
=> 2
```

or -

```
pry(main) foo = Customer.first
pry(main)> bar = foo.statements.where(some_param: 42)
pry(main)> bar.destroy_all
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  DELETE FROM `notices` WHERE `notices`.`id` = 4639
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM `notices` WHERE `notices`.`id` = 4640
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM `notices` WHERE `notices`.`id` = 4641
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
  . . . etc etc etc . . .
```

Comment: The problem I am having is that, if we do something like `foo.statements.where(some_param: 42).delete_all`, `foo.statements` is no longer what is actually in the DB.

Comment: In which case, reload statements: `foo.statements.reload`